# Script to replace default blogroll with links to my social media URLs

Tags: plugin-development, blogroll

I've got a plugin that I ship with my theme whose function is to jumpstart the process of launching site so that its optimized for the theme. It has all my default pages, plugins, settings, etc...

For example, I'm using the following script to remove the default blogroll links...

```
$arr_args = array( 'hide_invisible' => 0 );
$arr_links = get_bookmarks( $arr_args );
foreach($arr_links as $obj_link){wp_delete_link($obj_link->link_id);}
```

However, now I want to create replacement links to go in this listing. I want my social media links to go here.

Basically, I want to create a list of 4-5 links (YouTube, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc)

Once I know how to insert bookmark links via script, I can place the css bits in my theme that I need to effect the look.

Any ideas or examples for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [wp_insert_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_link).